# How to retrieve the text inside dropdown list by xpath

Tags: selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

I want to specify xpath to an element of my web page.

```
<select id=groupSelect>
   <option value="data" >First value</option>
    <option value="data" >second value</option>
</select>
```

I want to get the "First value" which is the text inside option. but I do not know how to get the text.

```
By.xpath("//select[@id='groupSelect']/option[@value=???']"))
```

Comment: Is it selenium and java bindings you are using?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`selenium` can [handle `select/option`](https://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/Select.html) in a nice and convenient way.

Here's how you can select the option by visible text (example in java):

```
Select select = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("groupSelect")));
select.selectByVisibleText('First value');
```

---

If you still want to have an xpath-based solution, you can check the option `value` and the `text`:

```
By.xpath("//select[@id='groupSelect']/option[@value='data' and . = 'First value']")
```

or get it by index:

```
By.xpath("//select[@id='groupSelect']/option[1]")
```

or you can check both.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, if I want to get the 3rd option element and want to check if that element exists or not how can I test it? Actually I have no idea how many items I have in dropdownlist.

Comment: @user3409650 you can put the call `select.selectByVisibleText('Third value');` into the `try/catch` block and see if there is `org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException` exception thrown - if thrown - there is no such option. Hope you understand what I'm trying to say.

Answer (score 1):

```
    import java.util.List;
    import org.openqa.selenium.By;
    import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
    import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
    import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

    public class Example {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.get("http://www.Example.com/");
    //List the Values
    List<WebElement> options = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@id='m']//option"));
    //Count the Values
    System.out.println(options.size());

    for(int i=0;i<options.size();i++){
    //Print the text
    System.out.println(options.get(i).getText());

    String optionName = options.get(i).getText();
    //If u want to select the perticular Value
    if(optionName.equals("xxxxx")){
    //Instead of xxxxx u put the value option 1 or 2 or 3 like that
    //If the value of option 1 is like Books, u want to select that put Books replace  with xxxxx   
    options.get(i).click();

    }
    }
    }
    }
```