# How do I select the drop down option

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I want to locate the following drop-down option using Selenium, but I'm unable to do so.

```html
<div class="customFonts" style="">
  <div class="fontOptions"><div class="fontView">
    <div class="fontDropDown">
      <div class="styledSelect customSelect">
        <select style="opacity: 0;">
          <option value="Arial">Arial</option>
          <option value="courier, monospace">Courier</option>
          <option value="Geneva">Geneva</option>
          <div class="toggleSwitchSliderInner">
            <img src="images/toggle_circle.png" style="display: block; right: -3px;">
          </div>
          <option value="Helvetica">Helvetica</option><!--This option-->
          <option value="Roboto">Roboto</option>
          <option value="sans-serif">sans-serif</option>
          <option value="sourceSansPro">SourceSansPro</option>
          <option value="times new roman, serif">Times New Roman</option>
          <option value="verdana, sans-serif">Verdana</option>
        </select>
        <span>Courier</span>
        <div class="customSelectIcon"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

How do I select the following drop down option. I keep getting element cannot be located. Please suggest

I tried the following two variants:

```
List<WebElement> b = driver.findElements(
    By.xpath("//div[@class='fontDropDown']"));
new Select(b.get(1).findElement(
    By.xpath("//select[text()='Helvetica']")));
```

which throws **element cannot be located**. And

```
List<WebElement> b = driver.findElements(
    By.xpath("//div[@class='fontDropDown']"));
new Select(b.get(1).findElement(
    By.xpath("//select/option[text()='Helvetica']")))
```

which yields **element should have been `select` but was `option`**.

Comment: Please include the code and the HTML as **text**, not as **image**, thank you very much. Therefore, **edit** your question.

Comment: Note that `get(1)` accesses the **second** matching element, not the first (indices start at `0`). I'm unsure if you want that (can't see the whole HTML). Also, sure that you want to find a `select` field and not an `option` field?

Comment: @Zabuza, thanks for your feedback. Yes, I want the second matching element.

Comment: I have updated it to select field, it still throws the same error "element cannot be located"

Comment: Okay. But please edit your question accordingly (include the HTML code). Also, please use the **format options** of the editor, especially for the code. Then you'll have my upvote and probably receive more help from others.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to retrieve the text inside dropdown list by xpath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26043240/how-to-retrieve-the-text-inside-dropdown-list-by-xpath)

Comment: Based on the linked question, it should be `"//select/option[...]"` instead of only `"//select[...]"`. Since you want to find based on the value inside the `option` element.

Comment: I have updated to the above and I am getting the following error  Element should have been "select" but was "option"

Comment: Please **edit** your question to include your other tries, instead of copying them to the comments where they are unreadable. Also, format your HTML, it is unreadable currently. Do it such that it looks like the image, well formatted. You may also use the **HTML snippet** option of the editor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first approach doesn't locate the element since the value is inside the **option**, not inside the **select** element.

Your second approach is better, but you try to wrap the result in a `Select`. This does not work, since the method returns a handle to the **option** field. Therefore, convert it to a `WebElement` by not wrapping a `Select` around:

```
WebElement option = b.get(1).findElement(
    By.xpath("//select/option[text()='Helvetica']"));
```

---

Since you want to **select this option**, you should actually focus on accessing the `Select` element and then using its methods to select one of the options. Therefore, take a look at the [documentation](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/Select.html) of `Select`.

Here are two variants:

```
Select select = new Select(b.get(1).findElement(By.tagName("select")));

// Select by value (the attribute)
select.selectByValue("Helvetica");

// Select by visible text (the text inside the tag)
select.selectByVisibleText("Helvetica");
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I will try and let you know.